# Looking for a term to describe this juxtaposition

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Our city is planning to re-purpose a Confederate Civil War Memorial by adding the names of Union soldiers & former the slaves who were freed in that era and fought for the Union. Would the joining of these three groups posthumously be an example of a Paradox? Irony? Is there any better word to describe this situation that came about against the will of each of the original parties?

Comment: Seems *inclusive* to honor Americans who died fighting.

Comment: The idiom "strange bedfellows" comes to mind, though it seems to simultaneously be a bit of a euphemistic understatement and to perhaps make unintentional metaphors about death and commonality...

Comment: Thanks to you both!

Comment: @PoundHash This is an after-the-fact description. I don't have to agree with the move. Probably a good move for the South to acknowledge the dead. And yes, there was the [Bitburg Issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitburg_controversy) of SS members buried with victims.